# How to know through which of the 2 channels the messages arrive [WebRTC]

Tags: javascript, webrtc, openwebrtc

I'm trying to identify which of the two channels a message came through, but I don't know how I can tell them apart.

How could I manage to do it?

```js
let channel = null;
let channel2 = null;

channel = connection.createDataChannel('data');
channel2 = connection.createDataChannel('data2');


connection.ondatachannel = (event) => {

// I'm sure it's here, but I don't know how to tell the difference.
channel = event.channel;
channel2 = event.channel;


// Regardless of whether channel or channel2 is typed, the messages are mixed up.

channel.onmessage = (event) => {}
channel2.onmessage = (event) => {}


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datachannels have a 'label' property that you set to `data` and `data2` respectively which gets signalled from the creator to the receiver. You can inspect `event.channel.label` and make decisions based on that.